# How much stiffness points on Shimano shoe is before it is noticeable?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, shoes

I'm debating over getting the older R171 or the newer but cheaper RP501.

R171 is listed as 10 stiffness index while the RP501 is 8, but it has boa dial and is the newer design and everything.

Can you notice between 8 and 10 Shimano stiffness index? If the stiffness is noticeable, I'd probably take R171, if it's not that noticeable, I might get RP501.

My only experience with Shimano is RP2 which is 6 in stiffness index, and it is a bit too flexy.

Comment: Best to go try them in a shop.

Comment: For best power transmission: the stiffer is the better. But the ability to adjust the 'lacing' wile riding is a non negligible plus.

Comment: I would be surprised if you could notice the difference in stiffness.

Comment: Too flexible shoe is easy to recognize by feeling the pedal through the sole. After that there's little benefit. My experience is from Mavic and Bont shoes, no idea about Shimano.

Comment: I ended up with RC701, stiffness rated the same as R171 but it has dual boa which is nice. Stiff enough for me.